# How can I change < to [ ?? I want the picture with 1 2 3 4

Tags: tikz-trees

[image: I want this style]

[image: I don't want this style]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{grow'=right,level distance=32pt}
\tikzset{execute at begin node=\strut}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={anchor=base west}}
\Tree [.S [.NP [.Det the ] [.N cat ] ]
[.VP [.V sat ]
[.PP [.P on ]
[.NP [.Det the ] [.N mat ] ] ] ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This could help http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/family-tree/

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to your code:

```
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style=
{draw,
edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.east)
-- +(8pt,0)
|- (\tikzchildnode)}}}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style=
{draw,
edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.east)
-- +(8pt,0)
|- (\tikzchildnode)}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{grow'=right,level distance=32pt}
\tikzset{execute at begin node=\strut}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={anchor=base west}}
\Tree [.S [.NP [.Det the ] [.N cat ] ]
[.VP [.V sat ]
[.PP [.P on ]
[.NP [.Det the ] [.N mat ] ] ] ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]